# How to schedule an email notification report with django-sql-explorer?

Tags: python, django

I'm searching for a reporting plugin for a soon to be developed django app and I checked some packages available in django.

I am particularly interested in using django-sql-explorer because of its flexibility with the queries. But I can't seem to find a setting to allow me to schedule a report and then send to email the reports. There is an option to send reports to S3 but that is not really what I need.

There is an option to email results via email but this only happens when the report is triggered manually.

Would there be another way to allow me to schedule a report to be generated and then send the result to email recipients?

Comment: Can't you use cron or celery-beat to do it for you?

Comment: thanks, I will look more into celery beat